# Swift Array Declaration Difference

Tags: swift-array

What is the difference between below declaration of array syntax in swift?

```
 var arr:[Int]

 var arr=Array<Int>()
```

and which one is better?
How and Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about Swift Array Declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668949/confused-about-swift-array-declarations)

Answer (score 1):

var arr:[int] this is fixed size array and don't change size after initialization.

var arr=Array() this is array list and this array change the size with respect to number of elements. you can easily remove and add element easily in this array.

Answer (score 0):

**var arr:[Int]**
This one simply declares an array of Integers named arr. It does not initialise the array and hence is not usable.

**var arr=Array()**
This one declares as well as initialises the array. We can add whatever we want to this arr.

The second one is better since its initialised and usable.