# Confused about Swift Array Declarations

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there any difference between the following?

1. `var array1_OfStrings = [String]()`
2. `var array2_OfStrings: [String] = []`
3. `var array3_OfStrings: [String]`

Testing in Playground shows that 1 and 2 are the same but 3 behaves differently. 
Can someone explain me the difference please? And also what will be the preferred way to declare an empty array of `String`?

Comment: @ogres that's wrong, #3 is not optional, thus it cannot be nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First two have the same effect.

1. declare a variable `array1_OfStrings`, let it choose the type itself. When it sees `[String]()`, it smartly knows that's type array of string.
2. You set the variable `array2_OfStrings` as type array of string, then you say it's empty by `[]`
3. This is **different** because you just tell you want `array3_OfStrings` to be type array of string, but not given it an initial value.

I think the first one is recommended as [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) uses it more often.

Answer (score 4):

While I might be late to the party, there is one thing that needs to be said.

First option set `array1_OfStrings` to array of Strings

The other option tells that `array1_OfStrings` is array of Strings and then set it empty.

While this might be a really small difference, you will notice it while compiling. For the first option compiler will automatically try to find out what is the type of `array1_OfStrings`. Second option won't do that, you will let compiler know that this actually is array of Strings and done deal.

Why is this important? Take a look at the following link:
https://thatthinginswift.com/debug-long-compile-times-swift/

As you can see, if you don't declare type of your variable that might impact build performance A LOT.